Laravel Pest. Customised folder structure. A single argument for Units and Features
I am trying to use Pest with a folder structure under single argument. I find this more readable.
Here an example of what I want to achieve:
tests/App/
      ├── Feature/
      └── Unit/
tests/Auth/
      ├─── Feature/
      └─── Unit/
tests/Comment/
      ├─── Feature/
      └─── Unit/

From the changes I made, Pest only finds the tests in the Auth folder.
So far I have changed phpunit.xml like this:
<testsuites>.
    <testsuite name=‘Unit’>
        <directory>tests/*/Unit</directory>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name=‘Feature’>
        <directory>tests/*/Feature</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>

and pest.php:
    uses(
        Tests\TestCase::class,
        Tests\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase::class,
    )->in(‘*/Feature’);

With these settings when I launch pest it only recognises only one folder (auth). With the command sail pest tests/app or pest tests/app/Feature it says: No tests found

What is the issue you are having?

@matiaslauriti you're right. I update my request. Basically, with ./vendor/bin/pest it only recognises just one foler, not all of them

I resolved change phpunit.xml like this:
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix=".php">tests/*/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix=".php">tests/*/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

Now I can use my folder structure.

The only change is that you added suffix=".php"?

yes, @matiaslauriti
